# How can a `System.Type` be a generic parameter with constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface, constraints

How can a `System.Type` be a generic parameter with constraints?

Here interface `I` has a single method `M` which classes `C` and `D` implement.

```
public interface I {
    void M;
}

public class C: I {
    public void M();
}
public class D: I {
    public void M();
}
```

Service instantiates a new T() (which is really `C`/`D` implementing `I`) and runs `I` interface methods on it

```
public class Service {
    public void Fn<T>(T t): where T : Type, I, new() {
        ( new t() ).M();
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will eventually be the public API for the service so I want it to be as concise as possible:

```
public class Main {
    public void main() {
        Service.Fn( typeof( C ));
        Service.Fn( typeof( D ));
        // ...
    }
}
```

This isn't compiling and the error is:
`'System.Type' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method ...`

The ultimate goal here is to be able to call `Service.Fn` concisely, as described in `Main`.  Any alternatives to my interfaces attempt are also welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to make a `C`/`D`? If so you should be using a generic argument such as `Service.Fn<C>()`.

Comment: C and D *are* types, but they do not *inherit from* `Type`.  Furthermore, you don't seem to understand the distinction between a type object (e.g., `typeof(C)`) and a type token (e.g., `Service.Fn<C>()`)

Comment: Aside from the syntax what is the difference between type object and type token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
public class Service {
    public void Fn<T>() where T : I, new() {
        (new T()).M();
        // ...
    }
}
public interface I
{
    void M();
}

public class C : I
{
    public void M();
}
public class D : I
{
    public void M();
}

static void Main()
{
    var service = new Service();
    service.Fn<C>();
    service.Fn<D>();
}
```

The issue was the superfluous `Type` in the `where` clause. `T` is a Type anyway by the fact it is a generic parameter - but an object of type `A` or `B` wouldn't be castable to the `Type` class - this is what `where T : Type` would mean.

In general, `where T: X, Y, Z` means that any `T` must (depending on what `X`, `Y` and `Z` are) either implement the interface, or be a subclass of, `X`, `Y` and `Z`. The `new()` constraint is slightly different, and makes the compiler aware that you also wish to be able to create a new object of type `T` in the method. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb384067.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d5x73970.aspx for more details)

Also, I've removed `typeOf()` from your input, as when you're using a generic the type can be referenced directly in the function (see above). Hope that makes sense. Any questions, just ask!

Answer (score 2):

This example may help you understand what's going on here:

```
void PrintTypeName(Type t) { Console.WriteLine(t.Name); }
void PrintTypeName<T>() { Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).Name); }

void Main()
{
    Type cType = typeof(C);
    Type dType = typeof(D);
    C cInstance = new C();
    D dInstance = new D();

    PrintNameOfType(cType.GetType());     //prints "RuntimeType"
    PrintNameOfType(dType.GetType());     //prints "RuntimeType"
    PrintNameOfType(cInstance.GetType()); //prints "C"
    PrintNameOfType(dInstance.GetType()); //prints "D"

    PrintNameOfType(cType);     //prints "C"
    PrintNameOfType(dType);     //prints "D"

    //does not compile:
    //PrintNameOfType(cInstance);
    //PrintNameOfType(dInstance);

    PrintNameOfType<Type>(); //prints "Type"
    PrintNameOfType<C>();    //prints "C"
    PrintNameOfType<D>();    //prints "D"
}
```

Comment: Fantastic example phoog!
If I may, I'll just add a helpful concept that helped me learn the difference:
`T` can be thought of as replacing any other type, eg `object`, `string` etc, whereas `typeof(T)` is a way of passing the type around as a variable.

Comment: @DavidEdey Thanks for your comment. I prefer to say "passing the type around as an object" but perhaps that's confusing. The real point, of course, is that `Type` is a class that describes types, while `Customer` is a class that describes customers. People get confused by the fact that `Customer` is a type, even though it's not true that `Customer` "is-a" `Type` (as the phrase "is-a" is used in teaching inheritance). A related confusion, of course, is the difference between static (compile-time) and dynamic (run-time) type. The example hints at that, but I didn't want to mention it explicitly.

Comment: Indeed! (and agreed, "passing the type around as an object" is clearer). It's very hard to explain it, and your code and above explanation are both fantastic!

Comment: @DavidEdey clearer, I don't know, because "as an object" might be taken to mean "as an `object`", that is, "as a `System.Object`" which is not really the point.

Comment: Mmm true! I guess it's just a pretty confusing point... Maybe we can say "`T` is a type, and can be used as replacing another type in code", whereas "`typeof(T)`, `tInstance.getType()` etc gives an object, which represents the Type `T`".. or maybe even just "whereas `typeof(T)` *is* an object". Not sure if that's any clearer either haha. Sorry this post is pretty pointless! haha

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the "proper" implementation would be to get rid of the `Type` constraint:

```
public class Service {
    public void Fn<T>(): where T : I, new() {
        ( new T() ).M();
        // ...
    }
}

public class Main {
    public void main() {
        Service.Fn<C>();
        Service.Fn<D>();
        // ...
    }
}
```

If you *really, really* want to pass in a type, then you'll have to use reflection instead of generics:

```
public class Service {
    public void Fn<T>(Type t) {
        I i = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as I;
        if(i != null)
            i.M();
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is you can't put a compile-time constraint that `t` is a type that also implements `I`.

Comment: You *can* actually inherit from type, even if it's not really what one wants to do.

Comment: I'm going to use your first version because it's cleaner/easier to use